# know the highest digit of a number

Tags: ios, swift3, base-conversion

I'm doing an app in Xcode 8 with swift 3 that is a base converter, the input value is set with buttons:

```
@IBAction func inputButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + (the number I want to add)
    labelText.text = "\(currentNumber)"
}
```

It works perfectly, but when I input about 10 numbers the app crashes. After the line where I set the new value for "currentnumber" Xcode shows me this:

Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_INPOV, subcode=0x0)

Comment: And what is the value of `currentNumber` at the time of the crash?

Comment: It crashes with any value I input for currentNumber

Comment: But you say "when I input about 10 numbers the app crashes".  So what is the final value when it crashes?

Comment: What is the type of currentNumber ? Int ?

Comment: For example, the number could be 230120203, and if i enter another number (any number), it crashes. That is what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow is (thankfully) an error in Swift.

You can prevent this in your code by checking if values would exceed `Int.max`, before actually performing the calculation.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
guard let inputNumber = Int(inputString) else {
    labelText.text = "input not a number or out of range"
    return
}

guard currentNumber < (Int.max - inputNumber) / 10 else {
    labelText.text = "overflow"
    return
}

currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + inputNumber
labelText.text = "\(currentNumber)"
```

Comment: My thoughts, exactly. But I wanted to make sure currentNumber was an Int before answering.

Comment: And is there any way to add more digits?

Comment: @DiegoEsc Use `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `Int`.

Comment: @nikolai how can I add decimal numbers? Thanks